# display the value of <input type="search"> input field on form after the first query (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

i am using an HTML5  input field on a get form to implement search on my site:

```
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="search" value="">
```

everything works, but after the first search the search string the user entered is not saved in the search field, rather the `placeholder` attribute  value is displayed again.

after the first search i would like to have the search string the user entered displayed in the search field on the form.

that means that `value` attribute of the input field needs to be "" before the first search (so that the `placeholder` attribute value will display) and then dynamically updated after the first search.

I understand from the `Mozilla documentation on <input type="search">`
 that the value the user entered is stored in the `DOMstring "searchTerms = mySearch.value;"` but my programming skills and experience are limited.

i am not using php, thank-you in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate and give example of expected output. You question is unclear now

Comment: edited question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `event.preventDefault();` on your function, with that your event will be canceled but the propagation of it won't. If you want to learn more about it, here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem with:

- DOMContentLoaded to trigger the javascript

[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

- URLSearchParams and URLSearchParams.get() to get query string

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get)

- getElementById to set value in input field

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

it is a common question-

([How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144))

```
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="search" id=mySearch required value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));
    let qstring = params.get("q"); // is the string for the query
    document.getElementById("mySearch").value = qstring;
});
</script>
```